# C# delegate equivalent when C++ using smart pointers

Tags: c#, c++, smart-pointers

I am mainly a .NET programmer working on a C++ project and am trying to determine the equivalent way to handle delegates that use the Action and Function template types.  I use the delegates both as events and callbacks within the .NET code.  My C++ project uses smart pointers and the same delegate design patterns as a C# program would.  What is the best way to handle this situation?  It is not clear to me how to pass and maintain a function pointer that also keeps track of the smart pointer and potentially the deletion of the underlying object since the event container uses a weak reference. The library needs to be multi-platform so using CLR is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Can you provide the C# code for reference?

Comment: What kind of smart pointer do you use ?

Comment: The smart pointer is a shared_ptr or weak_ptr depending on the situation.  The C# code is pretty standard, I don't think a specific sample would be all that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a method pointer bound to an existing object, that's it ?

The you should have a look for [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers). If your environment supports it, you can also use `std::tr1::bind` or even `std::bind` if it supports C++11.

The example which illustrates what you want is :

```
struct X
{
    bool f(int a);
};
X x;
shared_ptr<X> p(new X);
int i = 5;

bind(&X::f, ref(x), _1)(i);     // x.f(i)
bind(&X::f, &x, _1)(i);         //(&x)->f(i)
bind(&X::f, x, _1)(i);          // (internal copy of x).f(i)
bind(&X::f, p, _1)(i);          // (internal copy of p)->f(i)
```

> The last two examples are interesting in that they produce "self-contained" function objects. bind(&X::f, x, _1) stores a copy of x. bind(&X::f, p, _1) stores a copy of p, and since p is a boost::shared_ptr, the function object retains a reference to its instance of X and will remain valid even when p goes out of scope or is reset().

For the differences between `boost::bind`, `std::tr1::bind` and `std::bind`, I let you see [this other question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682919/what-are-differences-between-std-tr1-and-boost)

Comment: The problem with boost::bind is that I am developing a shared library and might have a boost version conflict between the client application boost version and the library boost version.  Is there a clean way to handle this situation?

Comment: It is a clean way, and you can set boost versions requirements. And that kind of functions won't change overtime (low probability at least). Have you considered the fact that it's an header-only ? And the fact that boost::bind has been integrated in the new standard, C++11 ? And were beforehand part of the TR1 ?

Comment: I need to use boost::signals to get the event functionality and lifetime control that comes with a C# type "event".  Is boost considered a reasonable dependency these days?

Comment: I don't know why you need that, it works like that. The only difference is that events are in fact arrays but you can easily do the same.
But yes, boost is a reasonable dependency =)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

It will also explain why delegates in C++ are a little tricky. This library was recommend in a game development book i read (So i'm assuming its very fast).