# What does std::tr1::_Bind mean?

Tags: c++

I am reading the code of an open source project, and found some code like:

```
template <typename F>
struct A : std::tr1::_Bind<F>
{
    ...
};
```

And the code using this struct is like:

```
A<void(*(PID<T>, void (T::*)(void)))(const PID<T>&, void (T::*)(void))>
```

I am very confused about these code, basically I do not know what `std::tr1::_Bind` means? And it seems no much useful info I can get from Internet.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682919/what-are-differences-between-std-tr1-and-boost

Comment: They're using a reserved identifier of a standard library implementation. Chances are this only works on a specific compiler/standard library implementation.

Comment: @Kay http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Comment: Just AOL to @Rapptz.

Comment: It will be related to std::bind (C++11)